# Isnumberic for textbox but the textbox accept alphabet

Tags: vb.net

I am using numeric for a textbox but if I key in the alphabet, the textbox also can accept it

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox1.TextLength = 0) Then
            MeanCalculateForm.Show()
            MeanCalculateForm.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only Number !!!!", "Error 
Message Alphabet")
                TextBox1.Text = ""

            End If
```

Picture screenshot -
https://ibb.co/PQb7zhz

Comment: If you want to test whether the `TextBox` contains a number then wouldn't it make sense to actually pass the `TextBox` contents to `IsNumeric`?  How does it make sense to test whether `TextBox1.TextLength = 0` is a number?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for a a Regex, use that on KeyDown event on your textbox,  a simple usecase would be

> /^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(.\d+)?$/

That Regex will allow for numeric value only(caters for negative numbers and decimals as well)

```
var regex = new Regex(@"/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/");
if(regex.IsMatch("Your character here")
{
   //allow the value to go through
}
else
{
   //set event as handled in your method
   //assuming args even is e
   e.IsHandled = true;
}
```

Comment: but if user want to copy n paste using the keyboard,it can use this code?

Comment: Yes, check the event that sets the value for the textbox  and use the same regular expression to validate the text(if the regex fails, set the textox as handled - you can optionaly throw your error message as well

Comment: I believe it was the Leave event, where you can determing what value was pasted into the textbox

Comment: the code u give me is paste into the button when click?

Comment: Yes, though the code is in c#, you migjt need to convert it to vb

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the keydown event

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

    Dim AllowedKeys() As Integer = {49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48,
                                 189, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 96, 109, 8, 46, 131089}

    If Not AllowedKeys.Contains(e.KeyData) Then
        If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = 67 OrElse
           e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = 86 Then

        Else
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: add 13 to the AllowedKeys array